# Update two tables in MySQL with two different WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I currently have two query over two databases. The first sets all values to 0 for a given user_id, and the seconds updates each user with a rank of 1.

```
UPDATE table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
SET table_1.value = 0,
table_2.total_value = 0
WHERE table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id =%s
```

and

```
UPDATE table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
SET table_1.value = 555,
table_2.total_value =1555
WHERE table_1.rank =1
```

I wanted to integrate them together, would this be possible..?

Comment: If there are 2 separate databases, the answer is no. They have to be in the same database.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
SET table_1.value = case when table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id =%s 
                         then 0
                         else table_1.value
                    end,
    table_1.value = case when table_1.rank =1 then 555 else table_1.value end,
    table_2.total_value = case when table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id =%s 
                               then 0
                               else table_2.total_value 
                          end,
    table_2.total_value = case when table_1.rank =1 then 1555 else table_2.total_value end
WHERE 
(
  table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id =%s
)
OR table_1.rank =1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `CASE` statements to set the value on the column.

```
UPDATE  table_1
        INNER JOIN table_2 
            ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
SET     table_1.value =     CASE WHEN table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id = %s THEN 0
                                WHEN table_1.rank = 1 THEN 555
                                ELSE table_1.value
                            END,
        table_2.total_value =   CASE WHEN table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id = %s THEN 0
                                    WHEN table_1.rank = 1 THEN 1555
                                    ELSE table_1.value
                                END
WHERE   (table_2.user_id = %s AND table_1.user_id = %s) OR
        (table_1.rank = 1)
```